# lagged difference with 2 vectors

Tags: r

I need a function to calculate difference between 2 variables and than its change over  1 lagged period of one of those variables. Formula looks like this:

[image]

Is there any simple way to achieve this without using more complex looping? I used `diff` function for regular percentage change of one vector like this:

`pcchange = function(x){  c( NA, diff(x)/x[-length(x)] ) }`

Is there any simple way by editing this function or example?

Comment: Why not just write it out: `c(NA, (tail(x, -1) - tail(y, -1)) / head(y, -1))` or maybe `c((tail(x, -1) - tail(y, -1)) / head(y, -1), NA)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy, vectorized, way to construct this would be to use `dplyr`. You could use the `lead` or `lag` functions.

```
vec1 <- seq(1,10)
vec2 <- seq(5,24,2)

library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(vec1, vec2, lag_diff=((lead(vec1)-lead(vec2))/vec2))

df1
```

> ```
>    vec1 vec2   lag_diff
> 1     1    5 -1.0000000
> 2     2    7 -0.8571429
> 3     3    9 -0.7777778
> 4     4   11 -0.7272727
> 5     5   13 -0.6923077
> 6     6   15 -0.6666667
> 7     7   17 -0.6470588
> 8     8   19 -0.6315789
> 9     9   21 -0.6190476
> 10   10   23         NA
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! However i have one simple question: how do I put NA on a start? So NA would be in place where `-1.0000000` and difference in last row?  Cant figure out how to manipulate this.

Comment: @Alexandros Sure so if you want to do that then you just use the lag function on the denominator and no functions where there is currently the lead function. That's kind of what I though you meant but I was going by the t and t+1 notation in the equation. So putting NA at the start means you'll be using t-1 and t instead of t and t+1.